# iOS - Image Metadata not showing up in PC, visible in online parser

Tags: ios, image, metadata

I am trying to add metadata to jpeg image, not using the Metadata dictionary provision in iOS, but using some tool that adds metadata as a header to the jpeg file.

Some Issues:
'Make' and 'Artist' don't show up in Mac/Windows if the length of the value is less than 5 characters.
The altitude reference doesn't show up in Mac.
'User Comment' field doesn't show up in Mac but shows up in Windows.

The issue is, that all these values show up if I check in an online parser (regex.info/exif.cgi)

The question is, is iOS expecting the Exif info to be in some specific format? If yes, what is it?

**Edit:** Even the altitude and longitude values are not correct. Lat comes as 0 0' 0" and longitude is x 0' 0", where x is  the value for hours that I set.
If I use the ususal method of saving metadata in iOS, I pass a decimal value for lat and long, but in this tool I pass hours minutes and seconds separately.

Comment: May you post one of these modified images for us to check? There are two major ways of storing metadata, EXIF and XMP; maybe there's a trick here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is specific format to store 'Make', 'Artist', GPS info and User Comments,
they have to be ASCII encoded and within the HEX tags (13B to 10E).
The user comments can be Unicode, however, not many metadata reader support that.

[On page 15 on EXIF 2.2 specification](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF), list of metadata attributes, and description of each attribute follow the table.

As side note, make sure you use proper EXIF metadata reader,
usually products skip reading the metadata if they counter any error reading it,
(ex. windows photo viewer)

Comment: Actually there was some problem while setting lat and long refs in the exif creator tool, so Mac and windows were not showing the lat and long correctly. I corrected that, lat and long appeared.  
But why did regex.info/exif.cgi this website show it correctly when mac and windows can't? It read 'everything' correctly, and now I know that exif creator I am using is wrong somewhere in the basics..

Comment: Great, it's working now. The problem centered on implementation  of EXIF specification, for both sides "reader" and "writer". Some implementation just neglect the details of these specification. Ex. PHP exif library, handles the whole header in ASCII, when the specification accepts Unicode for user comments. regex.info, I think , uses [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#library) for perl which is very powerful and been in the seen for long.